# Comparing java maps via hashing

Tags: java, collections, hash, comparison, compare

I want to *compare* two Java `Map`s by a simple hash.

*Each object is on a different computer, so sending a hash over the network will be cheaper that sending the whole object to compare.*

For example I have two `HashMap`s of an ExampleClass

```
Map<String,ExampleClass> One=new ...;

Map<String,ExampleClass> Other=new ...;
```

**I don't need to be sure that all elements are equal**, 
*it's enough for me to trust in a hash.*

I was about to iterate at each side and create a "homemade Hash", then send it to the network to finally compare for example an `int` or something.

It would be great if this "hash" is calculated every time an object is added or deleted from the Collection, saving me from iterate the whole object.  I have to encapsulate every add/delete of the `Map`.  Is there a Java library that does this?

Comment: Have you tried Object.hashCode() on the Map objects themselves?

Comment: How sure do you need to be about your answer?  Object.hashCode as everyone mentioned here may be good if you need an "okay" level of accuracy, however hash collisions can and do happen!  If you need a higher level of detection, you might consider using a cryptographic hash such as SHA-512.

Comment: Eric I think that's what trutheality puts as an answer @Steven "okay" level of accuracy is okay =) it's for keep a local map updated with a network map (to anticipate a temporized (but slower) update just in case hash fail )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your classes implement `hashCode()` (does not use the ["default" memory address hashcode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)) you can use the [map's `hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#hashCode%28%29).

The caveat here is that if your `ExampleClass` does not implement `hashCode()`, then equal items might have different hashes on the two different machines, which will result in different hashes for the maps.

---

To clarify:

`Map` implements a `hashCode()` that is defined as the **sum** of it's `Map.Enytry`'s `hashCode()`s.

[`Map.Entry`'s `hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode%28%29) is defined to be the **xor** of the key's `hashCode()` and the value's `hashCode()`.
Your keys are `String`s -- they have a well defined `hashCode()` (two equal strings always have the same `hashCode()`).
Your values are `ExampleClass` instances -- they *also need a well-defined `hashCode()`*.

In summary, a map that contains `{ s1 -> ec1, s2 -> ec2 }` will have a hashcode equal to:

```
(s1.hashCode() ^ ec1.hashCode()) + (s2.hashCode() ^ ec2.hashCode())
```

meaning that it *depends on `ExampleClass`'s `hashCode()`*.

If `ExampleClass` did implement `hashCode()` in a way that equal `ExampleClasse`s give equal `hashCode()`s, everything will work well.
If `ExampleClass` did not implement `hashCode()`, it will use `Object`'s `hashCode()`, which will almost always give you different `hashCodes()`.

Comment: If your classes which you're storing in the Map implement hashCode, and the Map you're using extends AbstractMap, then the documentation supplies the necessary happiness. "The hash code of a map is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of each entry in the map's entrySet() view."

Comment: ptomli and truth.., as I understand you say I have to implement hashCode(), like in @stefan answer, but at the same time, you say I can "use" the map's hashCode(), that's a bit confusing to me

Comment: I expanded the details in my edit. You do not need to re-implement a hashcode for `Map` -- it already has `hashCode()` implemented correctly. You **do** need to implement `hashCode()` for custom classes that you're _putting in the map_ (your `ExampleClass`). (You would need to do that even if you do go with stefan's answer)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is just to xor the hash of every object in the map, or some simple derivation thereof. Because `a ^ a = 0` and `a ^ b ^ a = b` for all a and b, (xor is commutative, associative, and its own inverse), and since xor is cheap, your add and remove can just xor the (possibly derived) hash code of the added or deleted item.

You may want to use a derived hash value to avoid cases where your map has all the same keys and values, but some of the mappings between them are transposed. A simple derived hash might be `key.hashCode() - value.hashCode()`, which would avoid most of these cases.

So, your code might look like:

```
public class MyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>{
    private int hash = 0;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {return hash;}
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V old = super.put(key, value);
        if (old != null) this.hash ^= key.hashCode() - old.hashCode();
        this.hash ^= key.hashCode() - value.hashCode();
        return ret;
    }
    @Override
    public V remove(K key) {
        V ret = super.remove(key);
        if (ret != null) this.hash ^= key.hashCode() - ret.hashCode();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note that some of the more advanced methods (eg. adding multiple items from a collection) may or may not be safe depending on implementation.

Comment: When adding multiple items is understandable to iterate the whole Map, but not for a single add/delete, although I would use other hash, this seem a good aproach to override put/remove methods.

Comment: This is a nice optimization since it updates the hashcode as opposed to recomputing it each time `hashCode()` is called. Although I would recommend to stay true to the definitions of `hashCode` that are given in the interface docs (sum of xors), which can also be implemented this way.